# Loop in ansible task description

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a requirement I want to use loop to create connector for kafka, I want to use table list in want to use config that will create configs for kafka connectors. for example(this is random example)

```
- name: Add-user-{{item}} # I want to use varaible in task name 
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    groups: "wheel"
  loop:
     - testuser1
     - testuser2
```

Want to use loop in task description

Comment: The task name is not repeated in a loop, so you will not see the diffrent items of the loop there.

Comment: What is your objective by having the variable in the task description? If it's for readability maybe you want to take a look at loop_control and label that could provide your custom outputs and each iteration. Just a thought. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach would be to use `loop` with `label`.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Example 1
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "Adding user {{ item }}"
    loop:
       - user1
       - user2
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Example 1] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Adding user user1) =>
  msg: user1
ok: [localhost] => (item=Adding user user2) =>
  msg: user2
```

Because it is adding files, complexity, I/O operations to your Use Case, a less recommended approach with [`include_tasks` module – Dynamically include a task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html) is shown in the following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Example 2
    include_tasks: add_user.yml
    loop:
       - user1
       - user2
```

using a separate task file **`add_user.yml`**

```yaml
- name: Adding user {{ item }}
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Example 2] ***********************************************************
included: /home/ansible_user/test/add_user.yml for localhost => (item=user1)
included: /home/ansible_user/test/add_user.yml for localhost => (item=user2)

TASK [Adding user user1] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: user1

TASK [Adding user user2] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: user2
```

**Documentation and Further Readings**

- [Limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)
- [Extended `loop` variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)
- [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950)