# Ansible role with a loop on variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a role called application_management.  In the tasks folder the `main.yml` contains :

```
---
- name: "{{ item }}"
  include_tasks: '{{ item }}.yml'
  loop: "{{ role_actions }}"
```

In my playbook I'm using the role with

```
- role: application_management
  vars:
    role_actions:
      - taskA
      - taskB
```

It is working BUT the 2 tasks are first included

```
TASK [application_management : {{ item }}] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /mnt/d/dev/ansible/roles/application_management/tasks/taskA.yml for host01 => (item=taskA)
included: /mnt/d/dev/ansible/roles/application_management/tasks/taskB.yml for host01 => (item=taskB)
```

and only after both tasks are executed but without anything to distinguish which one it is.

Is there a way of including taskA / executing taskA, including taskB / executing taskB ?

Or a way to retrieve the item variable inside taskA.yml/taskB.yml ?

And I see `TASK [application_management : {{ item }}]`.  Is there a way of getting the item name displayed ?

Comment: You may have a look into [Ansible: TASK description with `item`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77864840/6771046), [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950), as well [`include_tasks` module – Dynamically include a task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html).

Comment: Honestly it is not helping me.  The only thing I deduced is that what I want to do is not possible.

Comment: Right, that is the case, it is not possible in the way you are asking for. Why wouldn't such information not be helpful?

Comment: Why not run taskA.yml in one task and taskB.yml in the next task? Why does it need to be a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and only after both tasks are executed but without anything to
> distinguish which one it is.

This can be fixed with task naming. In the following example, the said role has named tasks in `taskA.yml` and nameless tasks in `taskB.yml`:

```
TASK [application_management : Including named tasks] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /Users/alexander/IdeaProjects/stackoverflow/77887421/roles/application_management/tasks/taskA.yml for localhost => (item=taskA)
included: /Users/alexander/IdeaProjects/stackoverflow/77887421/roles/application_management/tasks/taskB.yml for localhost => (item=taskB)

TASK [application_management : task 1 of taskA] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I am task 1 in taskA file"
}

TASK [application_management : task 2 of taskA] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I am task 2 in taskA file"
}

TASK [application_management : debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I am task 1 in taskB file"
}

TASK [application_management : debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I am task 2 in taskB file"
}
```

> Is there a way of including taskA / executing taskA, including taskB / executing taskB ?

Including in Ansible means dynamic loading. What you're describing is importing (static loading), which is possible using [`import_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html) module. But it's unsuitable for your use case because it cannot be used with a loop. With that being said, `include_tasks`, of course, still works as you expect in terms of running the tasks sequentially.

> Or a way to retrieve the item variable inside taskA.yml/taskB.yml ?

Sure, `{{ item }}` is a usual variable and will be available everywhere within the loop scope:

```yaml
# taskA.yml
---
- name: task 1 of {{ item }}
  debug:
    msg: "I am task 1 in {{ item }} file"

- name: task 2 of {{ item }}
  debug:
    msg: "I am task 2 in {{ item }} file"
```

However, I would not recommend using it like that because it restricts the reusability of your tasks.

> Is there a way of getting the item name displayed ?

No because the loop is not applied to it.

By the way, if you just want to include some tasks from a role and don't need the role to control its execution, you don't need a loop within a role. You can use [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html) module with `tasks_from`:

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Include tasks from the role
      include_role:
        name: application_management
        tasks_from: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - taskA
        - taskB
```